# UIPickerView selecting row zero if PickerView not touched

Tags: xcode, uipickerview

an annoying thing about PickerView that I'm trying to eliminate, is that if the user has to move off row zero and back on again to select it. I'd like it so that if the user decides to select row Zero, he can simply press the button to go to the next view and the row zero value will be selected.

any ideas?

Many thanks

here is my code - at the moment, if the button connected to saveSelectedCondition is pressed, and the pickerView is not moved off row 0, a null is returned for selectedCondition, rather than the condition value at row 0:

```
   - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        Condition *condition = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:row];
        self.selectedCondition = condition;
        NSLog(@"The '%@' condition was selected using the picker", self.selectedCondition.name);
    }

    - (IBAction)saveSelectedCondition:(id)sender {
        [self.selectedCondition setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"isSelectedCondition"];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
        NSLog(@"Saving selected condition (%@) with isSelectedCondition set to '%@'", self.selectedCondition.name, self.selectedCondition.isSelectedCondition);
    }
```

Comment: you want if user didn't touch picker then row 0 is automatically selected, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do, and I've sorted it out within the performFetch method

Comment: just put below single line code in your ViewDidLoad method and try

[pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

and let me know it will worked or not

Comment: here pickerView is your pickerview's object

Comment: @Pratik - thanks for the suggestion - it didn't work. However, I managed the workaround by setting the Condition instance that the PickerView didSelect was meant to select, i.e. selectedCondition, with key YES for attribute isSelectedCondition, for the Condition at Index zero emerging from the performFetch, i.e. row zero in pickerView. See my self-answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now sorted it out following performFetch with the following code:

```
 [self performFetch];
    NSLog(@"The following Conditions were fetched for the Picker by SelectorViewController:");
    for (Condition *fetchedCondition in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
        if (fetchedCondition ==[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:0])
        {[fetchedCondition setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"isSelectedCondition"];
            self.selectedCondition = fetchedCondition;}
        else
        [fetchedCondition setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"isSelectedCondition"];    
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
        NSLog(@"Condition: %@, isSelectedCondition %@", fetchedCondition.name, fetchedCondition.isSelectedCondition);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it....

```
- (IBAction)saveSelectedCondition:(id)sender {
    myText.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];//Just add this line for set first value
    [self.selectedCondition setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"isSelectedCondition"];
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
    NSLog(@"Saving selected condition (%@) with isSelectedCondition set to '%@'", self.selectedCondition.name, self.selectedCondition.isSelectedCondition);
}

Set first value when your picker view called.
```